# Couldn't find ` without an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Student table and a Sublet Post table in the database.

In the Student Show view

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<div>
  <h3>Sublet Post</h3>
  <%= link_to "New Sublet Post", new_sublet_post_path(:student => @student.id)%>
  <% @sublet_posts.each do |sublet_post| %>
    <%= sublet_post.created_at %>
    <%= link_to "Edit", edit_sublet_post_path(sublet_post.id) %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I passed in :student to the new sublet_post_path.

Sublet Post Controller

```
class SubletPostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_sublet_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /sublet_posts
  # GET /sublet_posts.json
  def index
    # get all the posts that are not taken and their linked properties
    @sublet_posts = Hash.new
    # get all students who created each post
    @students = Hash.new
    SubletPost.where(taken:false).each do |sublet_post|
      @sublet_posts[sublet_post] = Property.find(sublet_post.property_id)
      @students[sublet_post] = Student.find(sublet_post.student_id)
    end
  end

  # GET /sublet_posts/1
  # GET /sublet_posts/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /sublet_posts/new
  def new
    @sublet_post = SubletPost.new
    @student = Student.find(params[:student])
  end

  # GET /sublet_posts/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /sublet_posts
  # POST /sublet_posts.json
  def create
    @sublet_post = SubletPost.new(sublet_post_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @sublet_post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @sublet_post, notice: 'Sublet post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @sublet_post }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @sublet_post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /sublet_posts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /sublet_posts/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @sublet_post.update(sublet_post_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @sublet_post, notice: 'Sublet post was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @sublet_post }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @sublet_post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /sublet_posts/1
  # DELETE /sublet_posts/1.json
  def destroy
    @sublet_post.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to sublet_posts_url, notice: 'Sublet post was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_sublet_post
      @sublet_post = SubletPost.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def sublet_post_params
      params.require(:sublet_post).permit( :student_id)
    end
end
```

Sublet Post new

```
<h1>New Sublet Post</h1>
<h1><%= @student %></h1>


<%= render 'form', sublet_post: @sublet_post %>
```

In the new action, I did @student = Student.find(params[:student]) with the passed variable student. However, when I run this, it gives me a Couldn't find Student without an ID.

Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: What does the generated html for the link looks like? I mean this link `link_to "New Sublet Post", new_sublet_post_path(:student => @student.id)`, does that link include the student id?

Comment: @arieljuod Thank you, I edited the question.

Comment: `new_sublet_post_path(student_id: @student.id)`?

Comment: What do your routes look like?

Comment: @YLim you didn't answer what I asked, what does the generated `<a ...>New Sublet Post</a>` HTML looks like? do you see the student id on the HTML? I was not asking for the form template.

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing are nested resources - when you create a new `sublet post` you want to have the student who created it as well.

In order yo achieve that you could just add another input in the form, but that is not very elegant - you just came from the student show view.

This is what nested routes are for - the id for the student will be passed in the url, it will look like this

```
.../students/2/sublet_posts/new
```

We need this for both actions `new` and `create`.

Now in the routes file you can use it like so:

```
# routes.rb

resources :students do 
  resources sublet_post, only: [:new, :create]
end
```

Notice, that you only need to nest the new and create action - later you will have the id saved in the sublet_post instance.

Now first for the form:
It should look like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for [ @student, @sublet_post ] do |f| %>
```

Now your controller already has both variables defined, just be careful, you have to get the student like so:

```
@student = Student.find(params[:student_id])
```

This would be the correct way to do it. 
In order to link to the sublet posts new, don't just append the student to the path helper, but use `rails routes` in the terminal to find the right prefix for the path helper:

```
 new_student_sublet_post_path(@student)
```